# Here customer A and Customer B message to one supplier,supplier click the Customer A messages,only open the particular customer A messages

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here **customer A** and **Customer B** message to one supplier, suppliers click the **Customer A** messages and wants to open only the particular **customer A's** messages not mix both of them. But I am getting the output with both messages from Customer A and Customer B. Please help me to solve this.

[image: database image attached here]

**Model**

```
[public function customer_to_supply() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('communication');
        $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
        $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id');
        //$this->db->join('communication', 'communication.product_id=contact_supplier.product_id');
        $where = "communication.From' =>'customer'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $results = \[\];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $results = $query->result();
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

**controller**

```
    public function supplier_communication() {



     $supp_id = $this->input->post('suppid');
     $product_id = $this->input->post('proid'); 
     $cust_id = $this->input->post('custid');
     $this->session->userdata('cust',$cust_id);



    $result1 = $this->Profile_model->fetch_Data($product_id);
    $Userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $result3 = $this->session->userdata('tt');
    $data3 = array(
        'message' => $this->input->post('messagee'),
        'supplier_id' => $supp_id,
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'Customer_id' => $cust_id,
        'From' => $result3,
    );
    $this->Profile_model->data_insertt($data3);

     redirect('welcome/messageview');
}
```

Comment: What happen when supplier clicks on customer A? Are you passing customer id for filtering result?

Comment: yes i pass the customer id for filtering the result but still if we click the customer A it wil mix the Customer B messages also

Comment: You have to add customer_id condition in where clause in query like $this->db->where('Customer_id', 'Customer A id'); Also you have to clear old result of messages in html and then apply new messages in html.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the id of the customer ($customer_id) to your model function. Below is your function redesigned:

```
public function customer_to_supply($customerId) {
        $qry = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('communication')
                ->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id')
                ->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id')
                ->where('communication.From', 'customer')
                ->where('communication.Customer_id', $customerId)
                ->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
            return $qry->result_array();
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: k satafaka,how to get the customer id from communication table

Comment: You don't have the customer id? In your comments you said: "yes i pass the customer id for filtering the result but still if we click the customer A it wil mix the Customer B messages also". Please edit your Question and add your Controller function.

Comment: i wil try but it is not working,how to get the id from table, k i will ad my controller

Comment: Please add your Controller function to your post

Comment: i add the controller plz refere once